# Creating Array of Objects from Bash Array using jq

Tags: arrays, bash, jq

I am trying to create an array of objects in bash given an array in bash using jq.

Here is where I am stuck:

```
IDS=("baf3eca8-c4bd-4590-bf1f-9b1515d521ba" "ef2fa922-2038-445c-9d32-8c1f23511fe4")
echo "${IDS[@]}" | jq -R '[{id: ., names: ["bob", "sally"]}]'
```

Results in:

```
[
   {
     "id": "baf3eca8-c4bd-4590-bf1f-9b1515d521ba ef2fa922-2038-445c-9d32-8c1f23511fe4",
     "names": [
       "bob",
       "sally"
     ]
   }
]
```

My desired result:

```
[
   {
     "id": "baf3eca8-c4bd-4590-bf1f-9b1515d521ba",
     "names": [
       "bob",
       "sally"
     ]
   },
   {
     "id": "ef2fa922-2038-445c-9d32-8c1f23511fe4",
     "names": [
       "bob",
       "sally"
     ]
   }
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for id in "${IDS[@]}" ; do
  echo "$id"
done | jq -nR '[ {id: inputs, names: ["bob", "sally"]} ]'
```

or as a one-liner:

```
printf "%s\n" "${IDS[@]}" | jq -nR '[{id: inputs, names: ["bob", "sally"]}]'
```

Answer (score 5):

Split your bash array into `NUL`-delimited items using `printf '%s\0'`, then read the raw stream using `-R` or `--raw-input` and within your `jq` filter split them into an array using `split` and the delimiter `"\u0000"`:

```sh
printf '%s\0' "${IDS[@]}" | jq -Rs '
  split("\u0000") | map({id:., names: ["bob", "sally"]})
'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of null in this context?

Comment: @dan null cannot occur in C-strings, or anything that mimics them; therefore, they tend to be safe to use as delimiters. (As opposed to spaces, newlines, etc which sometimes *do* occur in the middle of normalish strings.) In this case, it looks like the strings are pretty plain, so newlines are probably safe enough, but that's not always true.

Comment: @GordonDavisson That’s true, however I tried this example with a bash array that had a multiline element, and everything was still split on new lines. With the accepted answer, it was split in to objects (`{ }`), and using nulls it was split in to arrays (`[ ]`).

Comment: @dan Can you provide your "bash array that had a multiline element" and how you created it?

Comment: @pmf I just threw a few new lines in to the questioner’s array, to test your answer: `IDS=("baf3eca8-c4bd-4590-bf1f-9b1515d521ba" $'ef2fa922-2038-445c-9d32-8c1f\n23511f\ne4')`

Comment: @dan You are right, I forgot to `--slurp` the input. Fixed it.